# How to identify which data belongs to which dataset after merging them in R?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge

I have two big datasets with over 3 million obs each and I used full_join to merge them together using the variable "N_AIH". Things is, in dataset 1 this variable is called "N_AIH" and in dataset 2 it's called "NUM_AIH". This is how I joined them:

```
join_test <- full_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("N_AIH" = "NUM_AIH"), keep = TRUE)
```

I have to keep both variables in the joined datasets,but now I need to identify:

1 - Obs that were in both datasets (the matches)
2 - Obs that were in dataset 1 but weren't in dataset2
3 - Obs that were in dataset 2 but weren't in dataset1

I can't seem to find a way to do it. I need to use the N_AIH/NUM_AIH variables.

Comment: I don't get it. With the full_join you already have what you need: 1) rows without NA were present in both data frames; 2) rows with NA in the "N_AIH" column were present only in the second data frame and 3) vice versa, rows with NA in "NUM_AIH" column were present only in the first data frame

Comment: well from the output of this code it seems that `full_join` retain both the columns: `set.seed(4)`
`dataset1 <- data.frame(id1=1:10,N_AIH=sample(letters,10))`
`dataset2 <- data.frame(id2=1:10,NUM_AIH=sample(letters,10))`

`join_test <- dplyr::full_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("N_AIH" = "NUM_AIH"), keep = TRUE)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Elia no you are not wrong. you are right. You should post this as the answer I guess

Comment: I think the OP has to provide a reproducible example or `dput` a sample of the data, to ensure that possible answers meet her needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset1 <- tibble(N_AIH = seq(5))
dataset1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   N_AIH
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     4
#> 5     5
dataset2 <- tibble(NUM_AIH = seq(3))
dataset2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   NUM_AIH
#>     <int>
#> 1       1
#> 2       2
#> 3       3

joined <-
  full_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("N_AIH" = "NUM_AIH"), keep = TRUE)
joined
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   N_AIH NUM_AIH
#>   <int>   <int>
#> 1     1       1
#> 2     2       2
#> 3     3       3
#> 4     4      NA
#> 5     5      NA

# observations present in both datasets
inner_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("N_AIH" = "NUM_AIH"), keep = TRUE) %>%
  distinct(N_AIH, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   N_AIH NUM_AIH
#>   <int>   <int>
#> 1     1       1
#> 2     2       2
#> 3     3       3

# Obs that were in dataset 1 but weren't in dataset2 
anti_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("N_AIH" = "NUM_AIH"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   N_AIH
#>   <int>
#> 1     4
#> 2     5

# Obs that were in dataset 2 but weren't in dataset1
anti_join(dataset2, dataset1, by = c("NUM_AIH" = "N_AIH"))
#> # A tibble: 0 x 1
#> # … with 1 variable: NUM_AIH <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>